# What does @remove mean in javadoc in Android framework

Tags: java, android, annotations, javadoc

I've been checking `ContextWrapper.java` in android sdk and noticed that there are some methods which are annotated in javadoc by `@remove`. I assume, it is an indicator to give lint warnings in IDE but that'd be great to know exactly what it is and why they needed such as thing in the first place instead of removing completely.

```
/** @removed */
@Override
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(File file, int mode) {
    return mBase.getSharedPreferences(file, mode);
}
```

[image]

Comment: no methods are annotated by `@remove` annotation in `ContextWrapper.java`

Comment: It does nothing, since its commented out

Comment: @pskink https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#170  in javadoc

Comment: see  Gabe Sechan's comment: `"It does nothing, since its commented out"`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I think there is misunderstanding so I rephrased the question. What does it mean of this? This method won't compile in normal circumstances. Why they keep it?

Comment: in `Context.java` you will see: `public abstract SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(File file, int mode);`, since it is abstract it has to be implemented in non-abstract classes extending `Context`, like `public class ContextWrapper extends Context { ...`

Comment: I just blindly relied on Android Studio in this regard and yes you are correct. I think it's an indicator to give lint warnings for IDE to not use it.

Comment: @GabeSechan That's a Javadoc tag.

Comment: @chrylis is right.  It removes the function from generated Javadoc.  But it does nothing to the compiled code or its function at runtime.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, but a Javadoc tag is a fundamentally different sort of thing from a commented-out annotation, and it's very likely to do something, just not to the bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `@hide`, it causes [Doclava](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/doclava/) (a Javadoc doclet Android uses to generate SDK documentation and API signature text files) to omit the annotated member from generated documentation and, if the `-api` flag is passed, from the generated API signature text file. If the `-removedApi` flag is also used, members annotated `@remove` will be included in the removed.txt signature file.